# How to mix hover event listener in mousedown event listener in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

htmlCODE:

```
<div class="original_circle" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: blue; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: 0">
    <div class="another_circle" style="position:absolute; border-radius: 50%; background-color: coral; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: -2"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.original_circle').mousedown(function() {
  $(this).find('div.another_circle').css('left', '50%');

  $('.another_circle').hover(function() {
    console.log('hover mouse in')
  }, function() {
    console.log('hover mouse out')
  });
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  console.log('mouse up')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="original_circle" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: blue; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: 0">
  <div class="another_circle" style="position:absolute; border-radius: 50%; background-color: coral; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: -2"></div>
</div>
```

This Code has circle. When I mouse down on class `.original_circle`, another circle(it's class is `another_circle`) has appeared from other space. 
And while I keeping mouse down, if my mouse is hover that `another_circle`,

```
$('.another_circle').hover(function(){
    console.log('hover mouse in')
    }, function(){
    console.log('hover mouse out')
});
```

These code have to be run.

But it didn't work well.

How can I make it works?

EDIT : add codepen

link  : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvYvWg

Above codepen, I want to change color of another_circle to red or orange.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @MEE console.log(hover mouse in) and console.log(hover mouse out) parts

Comment: Just to be sure: You know that when you 'hover' that excludes a 'mousedown' situation?

Comment: can you put this code on codepen and show exactly what's the problem?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I didn't know, thank you, so Is there no solution for this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. It all depends on what you want to achieve. You're setting up event handlers. Anyway, you cannot hover while the mouse is down, that much is clear. Have a look at the 'mouseIn' and 'mouseOut' events.

Comment: @yogihosting I edited, Would you check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the z-position of `another_circle`, that div is behind from `original_circle`, specifically `-2` down from it.

You could change the z-index attribute to something higher, like `z-index = 999`.

Further, JQuery best practice states that every selector execution must be stored in a variable, i.e: `var $anotherCircle = $(this).find('div.another_circle');` this is just for performance.

**Run this code snippet:**

```js
$('.original_circle').mousedown(function() {
  var $anotherCircle = $(this).find('div.another_circle');
  $anotherCircle.css({
    'left': '50%',
    'z-index': 999
  }).hover(function() {
    console.log('hover mouse in')
  }, function() {
    console.log('hover mouse out')
  });
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  console.log('mouse up')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="original_circle" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: blue; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: 0">

  <div class="another_circle" style="position:absolute; border-radius: 50%; background-color: coral; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: -2">

  </div>
</div>
```

See? now the mouseenter and mouseout functions are being executed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eleazar Enrique